# How to get Sampler Body data from beanshell Pre-Processor - JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I have Http Sampler body as follows,
{"Uname":"admin","Signature":"${Sign}","LoginTime":"${LogTime}","Action":"Do_Action"}

I have to get the value of "Action" from the above body, and that value nned to be sent to Pre-processor which will be useful to do further action.

Help me out of this...!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as:

1. Groovy has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
2. Groovy performs [much better than Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Example Groovy code to extract "Action" from the request body and store it into `${action}` JMeter Variable will look like:

```
def body = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
vars.put('action', body.Action)
```

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any way to do from Benashell pre-processor itself. SInce i have already written some code in beanshell pre-processor. I dont want to disturb it.. Is there any way to do so...??